# Win32 : MDI & Exit Code 18 (0x12)

Tags: winapi, mdi

I'm a beginner and trying to learn win32 API by following some tutorial.
I create a MDI window.

However, my window application is exiting with code 18 (0x12).

> Native' has exited with code 18 (0x12).

I have no idea why it is not exiting with code '0'.

**I replace PostQuitMessage ( WM_QUIT ) with PostQuitMessage ( 0 ) and the problem is solved.**

Next Question is:

1. What is the different between PostQuitMessage(WM_QUIT) and
   PostQuitMessage(0)?
2. How to have only one same submenu child window is opened.

[Can Open same submenu twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZDQw.png)

Comment: As a first step, look in `<winerror.h>` to find that error code, and/or use Microsoft`s `errlook` utility, and/or create one in C++ or PowerShell (in C++ you'd call `FormatMessage` and present the result).

Comment: ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES
18 (0x12)
There are no more files. what does it mean??

Comment: That sounds like something from an enumeration function, and seeing as your code doesn't invoke such a function, it appears unrelated. But it *could* have helped you, and often does. It's my first step with error codes. I don't see where it's coming from though. Very strange.

Comment: You don't do a whole lot of error checking. Why not?

Comment: @David Heffernan,, because I am a novice and  I do not know how to check error

Comment: The documentation for each API function tells you how. Typically by checking the value that is returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WinMain()` function is returning the `wParam` value of the last message received by `GetMessage()`, which is `WM_QUIT`.  Its `wParam` value is specified in the call to `PostQuitMessage()`.  You are passing `WM_QUIT` as that value, instead of 0:

```
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(WM_QUIT);
    return 0;
```

`WM_QUIT` has a numeric value of 18 (0x12):

```
#define WM_QUIT                         0x0012
```

That is why your program is exiting with code 18.

Comment: Thanks,, what is the different between PostQuitMessage(WM_QUIT) and PostQuitMessage(0)?

Comment: Simply a difference in whatever `wParam` value is assigned to the posted `WM_QUIT` message. You can set it to whatever you want, but since your code is returning that value from `WinMain()`, you will have to set it to whatever exit code you want to return.